# Tasks in externally triggered DAG do not run, target dag schedule=None

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I tried the airflow example DAGs to trigger the [target dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py) from the [controller dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py).
My code is the same as in the examples.

The controller dag executes successfully and triggers the target dag. The target dag is in running state but the tasks are not queued for execution.

[image: target dag]

This seems to be a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-43?focusedCommentId=15271578&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15271578) when the entire airflow system is not running in UTC.

Our metadata DB is in the local timezone. Since airflow 1.10 supports different timezones, is there a fix or workaround for this issue?

Running airflow 1.10.3.

Comment: Are you running the scheduler? Apologies if that's a daft question!

Comment: Yes. The scheduler is running.